# How to call a function inside of another function in js Class

Tags: javascript

I looked on whole stack overflow but unfortunately, answer of this question wasn't available so I have a class and inside I have a function donutMaker and inside of this function I want to call another function which is autoClicker but it is not being called:

```
class DonutMaker {
  constructor() {
    this.donut_creater = document.getElementById("donut_creater");
    this.donut_creater.addEventListener("click", this.donutMaker);

    this.auto_clicker = document.getElementById("auto_clicker");
    this.auto_clicker.addEventListener("click", this.autoClickerHandler);
  }

  donutMaker() {
    this.selection = document.getElementById("donut_quantity");
    this.quantity = this.selection.innerText;
    this.updated_quantity = parseInt(this.quantity);
    this.updated_quantity = this.updated_quantity + 1;
    this.selection.innerText = this.updated_quantity;
  }
  autoClickerHandler = () => {
    this.selection = document.getElementById("donut_quantity");
    this.quantity = this.selection.innerText;
    this.updated_quantity = parseInt(this.quantity);
    this.new_quantity = this.updated_quantity - 1;

    if (this.updated_quantity >= 1) {
      this.selection.innerText = this.new_quantity;
      this.quantity = this.new_quantity;
      this.selection2 = document.getElementById("auto_clicker_quantity");
      this.auto_clicker_quantity = this.selection2.innerText;
      this.auto_clicker_quantity = parseInt(this.auto_clicker_quantity);
      this.auto_clicker_quantity_updated = this.auto_clicker_quantity + 1;
      this.selection2.innerText = this.auto_clicker_quantity_updated;
      this.autoClicker;
    } else {
      console.log("Not Eligible");
    }
  };
  autoClicker = () => {
    console.log("Hello");
    // console.log("Auto clicker");
  };
}

let obj = new DonutMaker();
```

This line at the end of **if** supposed to call **this.autoClicker** but it isnt

Comment: `this.autoClicker;` does not call the function. `this.autoClicker();` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to **call** it

```js
this.autoClicker();
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [‘Calling Functions’ section of the mdn docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#calling_functions)

Defining a function does not execute it but calling it `this.autoClicker()` does.